# How to run Processing algorithms in QGIS 3 Plugins?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, qgis-3

In QGIS 3 I am trying to run Processing algorithms in a worker thread in a QGIS plugin (not a Processing plugin) using processing.run, and experience crashes.

I guess I need to provide a QgsProcessingContext when running algorithms, but have not found a way to get a proper one.

```
mycontext = QgsProcessingContext()    
inpbuff = processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT': self.inpvl, 'DISTANCE': radius, 'SEGMENTS': 10, 'END_CAP_STYLE': 0, 'JOIN_STYLE': 0, 'MITER_LIMIT': 1, 'DISSOLVE': True, 'OUTPUT': 'memory:'}, feedback=None, context=mycontext)
```

Both with and without the context parameter, I get many identical warnings before QGIS crashes:

```
Warning: QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

What is the recommended way of running Processing algorithms in a worker thread in a Plugin in QGIS 3?

Comment: I am not sure, if you aren't making this too complex or maybe I didn't get the purpose of the `QgsProcessingContext()`. Did you check out the syntax in the QGIS Python shell via `processing.algorithmHelp("native:buffer")`? According to this, I would try something like `processing.run('native:buffer',
                        {"INPUT": lineLayer,
                         "DISTANCE": 5,
                        "OUTPUT": resultLayer})` Or maybe the [QGIS API break documentation](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_Processing) helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been a problem with early versions of QGIS 3.

With version 3.4.2, I do not get these warnings and crashes when running algorithms in a separate thread in a QGIS plugin.